# Generating square fractals with Python

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

I need to write a recursive function with level as parameter that generates square fractals. Each square has to have a square in 3 corners.

What it should look like, levels 1, 2, 3, 4
[image: What it should look like, levels 1, 2, 3, 4].

I've tried something but I'm stuck. I get the first part done but then it gets stuck in the loop and I don't know how to continue.

This is what my code looks like:

```
from turtle import *

def fractal(level):
    global length
    if level == 1:
        forward(length)
        right(90); forward(length)
        right(90); forward(length)
        right(90); forward(length)
        return
    else:
        forward(length)
        length = (length / 2)
        fractal(level - 1)
        length = length * 2
        fractal(level)

length = 100
fractal(4)
```

Output:
[image: and the output]

Comment: Please, paste your code as text, not as a picture, so people don't need to rewrite it in order to edit it.

Comment: First of all, paste your code here. Remember about proper formatting. Use the (?) icon next to formatting options for help. Remember that the point is to make it easy to understand what you have and what is your problem. You can embed pictures instead of linking to them, but that's ok, code is more important

Comment: Then, please restructure your question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask (as to why you did it wrong) and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic with  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (for help on what you want to achieve).

Comment: That would be all on "how to behave on SO". Now, about your question: consider making "length" a parameter of your method and see what happens there.

Comment: @thomaso, you should've added your code as `formatted text`, not images. Images of output, if it's supposed to be some kind of graph, are fine.

Comment: @thomaso, ForceBru is right, but besides that, you didn't tell us what else did you try and why that didn't work. You are expected to take the effort and show us the real problem in your thinking.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

This code is overly complicated for achieving its goal.  I see two reasons for that: first your `length` global complicates things and makes the code non-reentrant (consider two turtles on two threads running this function at the same time.)  We need to make `length` an argument.  Second, most folks new to recursion overthink the problem and don't let recursion to do the work for them.  I would restructure this as follows:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def fractal(level, turtle, length, direction=90):
    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(length)

        if level > 1:
            fractal(level - 1, turtle, length / 2, -direction)

        turtle.right(direction)

    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(direction)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

fractal(4, turtle, 100)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

> the problem is that I HAVE to write a recursive function that can only
>   use level as a parameter, nothing else. That's why I have length as a
>   global variable.

We can lower the quality of the code to achieve your newly stated goals.

Note that without the `if` statement both programs simply draw a square, the basis of the fractal.  It's the `if` statement that introduces the recursion and the modifications that make the images smaller and the recursion ultimately end:

```
from turtle import *

def fractal(level):
    global length, direction

    for _ in range(3):
        forward(length)

        if level > 1:
            length /= 2
            direction = - direction
            fractal(level - 1)
            direction = - direction
            length *= 2

        right(direction)

    forward(length)
    right(direction)

length = 100
direction = 90

fractal(4)

hideturtle()
exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I understand that this can be done easier like that but the problem is that I HAVE to write a recursive function that can only use level as a parameter, nothing else. That's why I have length as a global variable.

Comment: @thomaso, I've adjusted my example accordingly.  Though it's import to understand why the global variable(s) are a hinderance in the long run.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I understand it, makes sense. Unfortunately I have to do an assignment and it requires a solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the code somewhere so that it can return back to starting point. And in your code the turtle keeps turning after drawing square, for three corners you need to turn it twice. Check below code. It's giving expected output.

```
import turtle


def fractal(level, tob, turn_direction=2):
    global length
    if level == 1:
        tob.forward(length)
        tob.left(90)
        tob.forward(length)
        tob.left(90)
        tob.forward(length)
        tob.left(90)
        tob.forward(length)
        return
    else:
        tob.forward(length)
        length /= 2
        fractal(level - 1, tob)
        length *= 2
        if turn_direction == 0:
            tob.forward(length)
            return
        fractal(level, tob, turn_direction=turn_direction - 1)


length = 100
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("light green")
wn.title("Turtle")
tur_ob = turtle.Turtle()

fractal(4, tur_ob)
```

Comment: You may be right, but you've given him a solution without teaching him anything. That's not SO, so I downnvote.

Comment: Code is same what he has already written. And regarding the modifications I have done, I have mentioned them with reason in the answer. I may not have explained them well. I will try to be more descriptive  from now on. Thanks you for letting me know my gaps. :)

Comment: @FilipMalczak he did explain what's wrong and provided a solution. that is the SO way. idk what ur on about. UPVOTE from me.

Comment: @HNMN3 Really appreciate your help. Thanks!